# Wordpress Update Links

Tags: urls, mysql

I just need a little help in WordPress query or a plugin which can update all internal links used as hyper link or directly with pages to WordPress normal url i.e `?page_id=69`

I have created a website with .htaccess mod_rewrite but unlucky the host which I am going to use not allowing to rewrite urls I have about 140+ Pages so I can't just update links 1 by 1

I have also changed the links to default but that only works for main menu not internal pages.

IN SHORT I JUST NEED TO UPDATE ALL URLS FROM:

```
 http://localhost/wordpress-website/about
```

to

```
 http://localhost/wordpress-website/?page_id=40
```

Comment: You can do that from `settings->permalink` option.

Comment: I have done that.. but still pages which are manully linked need to be changed

Comment: `pages which are manully linked need to be changed` - **Manually** created links need _manual_ fixing. You may try [search and replace plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/), though.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE @user38002. Please refrain from using [all caps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps).

Comment: search and replace plugin.. i don't think its going to work there are 140+ pages and links each page is link to individual page or post..

It will be a nightmare for me to update 1000 individual links there must be some MySQl way :(